# Why do classes needs an __init__ function to pass parameters to class instances?

Tags: python

I am trying to understand why do we need an `__init__` function in classes to pass parameters to class instances.

Normally, when you want a class instance to have parameters, you do this:

```
class bruh:
    def __init__(self, par1, par2, par3):
        self.par1 = par1
        self.par2 = par2
        self.par3 = par3

newThing = bruh(1, 2, 3)
```

I was wondering why can't we simply do this:

```
class bruh(self, par1, par2, par3):
    self.par1 = par1
    self.par2 = par2
    self.par3 = par3

newThing = bruh(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: The first one is instance attribute which you will see like `newThing .__dict__` and the latter is class attributes `bruh.__dict__`, Try change one and see the reflection in `.__dict__` Please read this https://www.python-course.eu/python3_class_and_instance_attributes.php

Comment: This makes me think of how JavaScript started out doing things... and the experience has taught that it comes with its own problems... It later came with a `class-constructor` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always make your own language with that syntax. In Python, we use `class ClassName(parents...)`. The stuff in the `()` should be the parent classes.

Note that `__init__` has a subtler meaning. It initializes instance fields, and it does not construct instances. The constructor is `__new__`. Thus, your proposal would not be as fluid as you might think it is.

Also note the scope issue. You can think of Python's classes like a module.

It'd be quite awkward to define instance methods using your proposal. Have you thought about how you'd define and use static or class methods and fields?

```
    class bruh(self,par1,par2,par3):
        self.par1 = par1
        self.par2 = par2
        self.par3 = par3
```

Answer (score 0):

The **init** method is the standard initializer for every class when an instance is created.

You could define variables as such:

```
class bruh():
    # Class variables common to every instance of the class
    a = 2
    b = 1
    
    def __init__(self):
        # Instance variables specific to that specific instance
```

This is how the python interpreter works to differentiate class and instance variables.

Comment: `__init__` is an initializer (you can call it many times). `__new__` is the constructor: it makes a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

One reason is that in python, classes are mostly just regular objects. To make a class, you call its [metaclass](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses) (which is a class that makes classes). The syntax `class bruh(...)` is reserved for passing arguments to the metaclass.

The most common metaclass is [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type). The `class` keyword and what follows it are syntactic sugar for calling `type` on a namespace that includes the class body. So your class declaration could have been written something like

```
def __init__(self, par1, par2, par3):
    self.par1 = par1
    self.par2 = par2
    self.par3 = par3
bruh = type('bruh', (), {'__init__': __init__})
del __init__
```

In this case, you are not passing in any keywords in `class bruh:`, but that is how you would modify the initialization process, as well as set the metaclass if you did not want to use `type`.

`__init__` is just a regular method: you can call it as many times as you want on an object once it's been created. When you call the class `bruh`, you are doing a lot more than just calling `__init__`. You are actually calling `type.__call__(bruh)`, which, as a minimum, calls `object.__new__(bruh)` (since `bruh` does not define a `__new__` classmethod), to make the new object, and then calls `__init__`.

Making classes regular objects, and separating out object creation and initialization makes python that much more flexible. At the same time, you have that much more detail to understand if you want to use the full power of that flexibility.